# How many downloads at a time can NKAssetDownload make?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, newsstand-kit

Is it possible to make multiple downloads at a time?

Answer (score 2):

When you send downloadWithDelegate message to NKAssetDownload the Newsstand framework just add it into its queue to download. After that there is no control in developer's hand as to when download starts. As far as I can tell from my experience, it do not start 2 download simultaneously. When one completes it start another one from the queue. I don't know why it is implemented this way but no parallel download.